# FieldError at /admin/login/ after customizing default User model

Tags: python, django

So I customized my default User model because i didn't like the default fields the model had, i wanted to add my own fields and completely override the default. Now when ever i go to localhost:8000/admin/, I login and get this error:

```
FieldError at /admin/login/

Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: admin_email, admin_gender, admin_password, admin_position, admin_username, dateregistered, emailaddress, farmadministrator, farmemail, farmname, farmpassword, farmphonenumber, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, password, socialaccount, storefeedsale, storemedictaionsale, user_permissions
```

The django traceback doesn't link the error back to my code code rather to some django code;

Traceback:

```
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
The above exception (integer out of range ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/views.py in register_view
            regform.save() …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/forms.py in save
            self.cleaned_data['companypassword'], …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/record_Buddy/record_Buddy_Network/models.py in create_user
        user.save(using=self._db) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py in save
        super().save(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save
                       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in save_base
                force_update, using, update_fields, …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _save_table
            results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in _do_insert
            using=using, raw=raw, …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
                cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
            return super().execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__
                raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value …
▶ Local vars
/home/thefixer/django_stuff/django_job/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) …
▶ Local vars
```

so im very confused please i need help. my custom User model which i also renamed to recordBuddyUser;

Below is my custom User model which i renamed to recordBuddyUser, I wanted to specify my own fields in the database although now I think of it I might have gone over board with it. Also i put the admin-user fields inside the same model (recordBuddyUser) as the regular fields i hope thats alright.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    PermissionsMixin,
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
)


# Custom models to override django default User and handle all User intercations

class User_manager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, companyname, companyemail, companyadministrator, companyphonenumber, companypassword):
        companyemail = self.normalize_email(companyemail)

        user = self.model(companyname=companyname, companyemail=companyemail,
                          companyadministrator=companyadministrator, companyphonenumber=companyphonenumber,
                          companypassword=companypassword,
                          )

        user.set_password(companypassword)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, admin_username, admin_email, admin_gender, admin_password, admin_position):
        user = self.create_user(admin_username=admin_username, admin_email=admin_email,
                                admin_gender=admin_gender, admin_position=admin_position, admin_password=admin_password
                                )

        # user.set_password(admin_password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class recordBuddyUser(PermissionsMixin, AbstractBaseUser):
    ''' This model handles the details of users on Aqua Buddy '''
    companyname = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    companyemail = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default=None)
    companyphonenumber = models.IntegerField()
    companypassword = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default=None)
    companyadministrator = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # companylogo = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True)
    dateregistered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # companyletterhead = models.CharField(max_length=2083, null=True)

    # recordBuddy Admin fields

    dateregistered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    admin_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, default=None, unique=True)
    admin_position = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    admin_username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    admin_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=2083, default=None, blank=True)

    gender_choices = [("M", "Male"), ("F", "Female"), ("O", "Others")]
    admin_gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices,
                                    default="M", max_length=1, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["admin_username", "admin_email", "admin_position"]
    USERNAME_FIELD = "companyname"
    objects = User_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.companyname
```

I can't tell what is missing but offcourse the computer isn't wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the view function for the route `/admin/login/` is expecting your `User` object (in this case, a `RecordBuddyUser` object) to have an attribute `username` to create a form field for it.

You can edit that view function, or better yet, write your own using that one as a guide, to use whatever attributes you want from your custom class to login.

I would suggest writing your own since you are overriding the builtin `User` class and will probably need to change multiple view functions to get everything working.

You also might want to read about how other people have tackled this problem online. Replacing or extending the builtin Django User Model is very common and there are packages that can help with this too.